# What are the standard numbers for fuel consumption (kg), kg/NM, and kg/h, of Boeing 737-300?

Tags: boeing-737, fuel, boeing, performance-calculation, fuel-consumption

I'm currently working on a school project regarding the analysis of Boeing 737-300 fuel consumption. I'm working on some parameters that my supervisor gave me, which are :

1. Total fuel consumption (kg),
2. Fuel consumption per Nautical Miles (kg/NM), and
3. Fuel consumption rate (kg/h)

I'm curious if there are specific informations in the industry, or from OEM, or from the manufacturers, regarding the standard of the numbers of these parameters from B737-300 flights, official/reliable references in essence, so i can use them for benchmark to my calculation results

Been searching for lots of reliable references that i can use before, but the best i can find are forum posts with a rough number, or some random aviation websites, and i'm not quite convinced to use them as my benchmark/reference in my report

Answer (score 5):

There are charts out there, but the rule of thumb is 5,000 lbs per hour average for a flight. The first hour is more given the higher fuel flow at takeoff & initial climb, but as an average that's a reasonable ballpark.

If I need more precise values, I'll either look at the fuel flow gauges in the engine instruments (for an indication corresponding to the present conditions), FMC fuel projections (which is computed burn from now until landing), or I'll have a dispatcher generate a computer flight plan (for cases like determining the burn to get to a particular alternate, or if we operate a flight at a different altitude or using a particular route).

If you need for specific numbers, others may be able to provide charts that consider aircraft weight, flight altitude, and temperature, but for a first approximation, 5,000 pph works fairly well for most cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the appropriate [airport planning document](https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/737CL_REVD.pdf).  Airline manufacturers make them available.

It contains a ton of information, you'll want to check out the payload-range diagram.  For the -300, it is on page 69 of the above document.

In particular, you'll want to check out the slanted lines labeled by their break release gross weight.  The negative slope of these lines is the specific range (nmi/lb) of the aircraft.

You may be able to search around for a pilots operating handbook (POH) that will contain more details.  Unfortunately, the chapter of interest (aircraft performance) is often left out of the POH's available online.